# What exactly is included when I backup my iPhone 4 using iTunes?

Tags: itunes, iphone, backup

I have read this question [Does an iTunes iOS device backup include everything on the device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/does-an-itunes-ios-device-backup-include-everything-on-the-device) but it doesn't seem to be explicit/succinct enough and I can't find a clear list of what exactly is and isn't backed up anywhere that I would trust.

Specifically I am asking which of these things are backed up ( and if there are any others which I am leaving out )

- Settings inc email settings and and wifi passwords
- Applications and their settings
- Photos
- Videos
- Songs
- Notes
- Reminders
- Calendar
- Voice Memos
- Contacts
- SMS's
- Firmware ( which I gather is not backed up )

I have a feeling that various parts of the backup are stored in various locations so maybe that might be explained, and also I read somewhere that the backup only includes the media items if a sync has been performed so could this be explained ... ie do I have to also do a sync to ensure a full backup.

I have an iphone4 and I am backing up to my computer as opposed to iCloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a great article enumerating what gets backed up for each level of iOS.

- [iTunes: About iOS backups](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946)

Pay close attention to the section titled **iTunes will back up the following information** and note that by setting a passcode, Apple backs up more of your device's keychain. Also [this article covers using iTunes and iCloud to back up](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5262) since each has strengths and weaknesses in terms of backing up an iOS device.

In terms of the things you enumerate - all are backed up except the one you didn't want (the OS itself and firmware for the device).

I would encourage you to also sync contacts (and other data) so you have a second backup (or even the ability to make a third backup of the synced data) since losing contacts is an event that is very painful to recover.